# Multiple colored Activity Label element on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the Label element be made up of two different colors. For example, my label is "MyLabel" and I'd like the "My" part to be in red and the "Label" part to be in blue.

I tried working with this guide, but this approach would only be applicable for one color.
https://blog.qualtechsoftware.com/how-to-customize-the-title-android-with-xamarin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at *SpannableString* in the Android documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

```c#
    var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_label);
    var span = new SpannableString("My Label");

    span.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), 0, 2, 0);  // "My" is red
    span.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Blue), 3, 8, 0); // "Label" is blue
    textView.SetText(span, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

Comment: Perfect concise answer for someone migrating from native android development to Xamarin. Thanks!